# LLPSI: Ch. 14, Ln. 38, "et oculōs aperiēns..."

Tags: syntax, lingua-latina-per-se-illustrata, participle

My question stems from a passage of Lingua Latina Per Se Illustrata Familia Romana in chapter 14 on page 104 beginning at line 38 as follows.

**Question**

Does "aperiēns" modify oculōs even thought it is plural, and if not, how should the sentence beginning with "Eō modō excitātur Mārcus,..." be read?

[image]

Comment: What may have confused you is that, in English, *to open* can exist as both a transitive verb ("he opened his eyes") and an intransitive verb ("his eyes opened"). I think *aperio* "uncover, open" is only used transitively.

Comment: @Cerberus Well, not really: e.g. _Foris aperit_ (Pl. _Pers_. 300) ‘The door is opening’. See https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/9421/how-things-change-in-latin

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Aperiēns* is an active present participle, which is a verb form that can take a direct object. *Aperiēns* and *oculōs* go together, but not by means of *aperiēns* modifying the noun; the noun is the direct object of *aperiēns.*

The meaning is "Opening (his) eyes" and it serves to describe the state of the subject of the sentence, *Mārcus*, with which *aperiēns* agrees in number, gender and case.

A shorter version of the sentence with the same construction would be "Mārcus, oculōs aperiēns, servum videt." The full sentence in LLPSI has another active present participle that agrees with the word "servum".