# Translate "Before the Fire" and "After the Fire" into Classical Latin

Tags: classical-latin, english-to-latin-translation, translation-check

I am translating the phrases "Before the Fire" and "After the Fire" into Classical Latin. These are used for dating in a fashion similar to how B.C.E./B.C. and C.E./A.D. are used for dates in the western world.

*Ante Incendium* and *Post Incendium* seem like the obvious choices, assuming that the noun makes sense, but is there something potentially more poetic sounding?

Edit: Per a comment from [brianpck](https://latin.stackexchange.com/users/45/brianpck) and [a post](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/12608/translate-everything-burns-into-classical-latin) I made before about translating "everything burns" into Latin, would something like *ab Omnibus Incensis* make sense, and how would that be abbreviated?

Comment: What kind of fire are you talking about? If it were something like the London fire, you could do a neat parallel with the usual Roman way of counting years: *ab urbe incensa*

Comment: Atomic or nuclear fire, although I'm totally open to something more like the London fire for the parallel with Roman year counting. The "fire" in question isn't limited to one particular city, though.

Comment: I edited my post with an idea I just had based off your comment, @brianpck.

Comment: I fully agree with brianpck. The use of a so-called "dominant participle" construction (aka _ab urbe condita_ construction; cf. https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/9412/how-obligatory-is-the-predicate-in-a-dominant-participle-construction ) is indeed quite idiomatic in Latin. E.g., cf. _**ante Capitolium incensum**_  (Livy VI, 4).

Comment: *Ab omnia incensa*: Your instinct is right, but it needs to go into the ablative, *ab omnibus incensis*

Comment: Ahh, thanks for that. I've updated the post to use the ablative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Incendium* is a good word for a big, out-of-control fire, and you've used it correctly. But if you don't want to be that literal, how about **ruīna**? It's the source of English "ruin", but means something like "catastrophe, calamity, downfall, disaster"—Vergil uses it when talking about the fall of Troy.

If you go with this, you could mark your years **ante ruīnam** and **post ruīnam**: "before the destruction" and "since the destruction".

Comment: This is great! It would be very easy for an English-speaker to understand. Would abbreviating these as A.R. and P.R. be accurate?

Comment: @Adam Seems reasonable to me! (You'd also probably use a normal _i_ without the long mark on top; I just use the long marks because it helps me keep in practice.)